# Azure AD B2C ClaimsTransformation to non null input claim

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In Azure AD B2C I am having multiple technical profiles.

In one technical profile, I may or may not have value for an output claim. But I can get it from another claim. Here for example let's take email.

So, it is possible that the user may not have an email claim, which is needed in the output. I can get it from the signInName as well.

What I want is to achieve is

1. if email claim has value, pass email claim in output
2. else use the claim signInName with PartnerClaimType="email"

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What type of technical profile is this?

Comment: It is AAD-OIDC.

Answer (score 0):

Use in AAD-OIDC:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
```

If `email` has a value at this stage, it will be output into the claimbag, else itll be `null`.
It will always try to map `signInName` claim to the `email` claim coming from AAD federation.

You cannot explicitly control what will get output based on another claim within the same technical profile.

What you can do is "if email exists, set signInName to null" **after AAD-OIDC completes**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#nullclaim

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="SetSignInNameToNull" TransformationMethod="NullClaim">
  <OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="claim_to_null" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

```xml
  <TechnicalProfile Id="CT-SetSignInNameToNull">
    <DisplayName>Compare Email And Verify Email</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetSignInNameToNull" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  </TechnicalProfile>
```

```xml
        <OrchestrationStep Order="X" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
<!-- precondition here to only run this step if Email exists, and it was AAD Federated auth -->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>email</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SetSignInNameToNull" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CT-SetSignInNameToNull" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a single claims transformation?

Comment: That is a single claim transform.

Comment: What I expected is to have a claims transformation where we check if the value a is null or not. if not null, we pass value a, else we pass value b. I can then call this transformation directly from the technical profile.

Comment: Not possible, at the link you can see all claims transforms available.